# Using vba to filter data between two values

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, first one is called Enter, second is called Results

I have two cells E2 and F2. E2 allows the user to input alower bound, F2 allows the user to input an upper bound that I need to use to autofilter the data in the Results sheet. Column D in the results sheet is titled Number.

I've tried to make a start but not sure how I would filter between two values.

```
Worksheets("Results").Range("D2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    ">" & Worksheets("Enter").Range("E2").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Worksheets("Entry").Range("E3").Value
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use `Value2` rather than `Value`, especially if your regional settings are not US format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by not declaring your range to filter correctly as in your code you're only looking at cell D2 to filter

try

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")

With ws
    .Range("$D$2:$D$" & .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">" & Worksheets("Enter").Range("E2").Value, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<" & Worksheets("Entry").Range("E3").Value
End With
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**
To ignore the filter if conditions are empty use:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Enter As Worksheet
Dim Entry As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
Set Enter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Enter")
Set Entry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Entry")
If Not IsEmpty(Enter.Range("E2")) And Not IsEmpty(Entry.Range("E3")) Then
    With ws
        .Range("$D$2:$D$" & .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=">" & Enter.Range("E2").value, _
            Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:="<" & Entry.Range("E3").value
    End With
End If
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I've rewritten a lot of the code to include that you're using tables and to include the second filter as detailed in the comments. I've also commented the code to help you understand what it's doing and why

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Dim Enter As Worksheet: Dim Entry As Worksheet
Dim NoRow As Integer
Dim c

' Turn off screen updating (code runs faster)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set worksheets to variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
Set Enter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Enter")
Set Entry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Entry")

With ws.ListObjects("Results")
    ' Reset the filter for the Results table
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    ' Test to see if between criteria is set if not the results table will stay unfiltered
    If Not IsEmpty(Enter.Range("E2")) And Not IsEmpty(Entry.Range("E3")) Then
        ' Find how many Locations are set to show. If none macro will exit the sub
        With Entry.ListObjects("Location")
            .Range.AutoFilter field:=.ListColumns("Show").Index, _
                Criteria1:="Show"
            ' Error handling
            On Error Resume Next
            NoRow = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        ' Filter 'Show' Locations
        If NoRow = 1 Then
            .Range.AutoFilter field:=.ListColumns("Location").Index, _
                Criteria1:=Entry.ListObjects("Location") _
                .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
        ' Handle if all Locations are hidden
        ElseIf NoRow = 0 Then
            MsgBox "All Locations are hidden"
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If

        ' Filter Area with between criteria
        .Range.AutoFilter field:=.ListColumns("Area").Index, _
            Criteria1:=">" & Enter.Range("E2").Value, _
            Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria2:="<" & Entry.Range("E3").Value
    End If
End With

CleanUp:
    ' Reset Location table to show all Locations again
    Entry.ListObjects("Location").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Is there a way to NOT filter the list if no value is present in either E2 or E3? Likewise, if 500 min was set as the min value, with no max value, would there be a way to show all values above 500?

Comment: Thank you. This is unrelated, but say I also have a 2x2 table on my entry sheet, with column H containing Location 1 and Location 2, with column I having drop downs next to each option (Show or Hide) - is there a way to also filter the table in the Results sheet? Column C in the results sheet contains either Location 1 or Location 2 for each entry. However, I'm struggling to do multiple filters.

Comment: Hi Tom, when I tried the If statement, it works, but it stores the information from the last entry. So if I put in 500 and 10,000, and then clear the entries, the Results sheet will still show those entries in between those values, rather than resetting to show all entries

Comment: Ok, that's not what you asked for but is a simple fix using `else ws.ShowallData` in the `if` statement

Comment: I'm just updating both my update and to include the second `autofilter`

Comment: What is the name of your table in the Entry sheet?

Comment: Location. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96054/discussion-between-tom-and-sam-wells).

Comment: Hi Tom, I just sent you a message via chat as I'm getting an error with the script regarding the line: With ws.ListObjects("Results") - I've defined my table in the Results sheet as "Results" bu this isn't working