# excel vba select range between two numbers

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, range, countif

[image: Select range between two numbers]

1. C column is sorted from the input data
2. From the sorted output, the selected range should be with in -0.25 to +0.25

How to add more than one criteria in COUNTIF function or its similar function?

**Original syntax:**

```vb
.Resize(Application.CountIf(.Cells, "<0")).Select
```

**Requirement:**

```vb
.Resize(Application.CountIf(.Cells, ">-0.25 & <0.25")).Select
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [autofilter](https://www.exceldome.com/solutions/filter-between-two-numbers/) to filter column c between these two values? Google around for examples. And even on SO there are examples if you look for them. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896599/using-vba-to-filter-data-between-two-values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `CountIf` with `CountIfs` when you want more than one condition. Try this:

```
.Resize(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Cells, ">-0.25", .Cells, "<0.25")).Select
```

Comment: It worked, actually I missed the "WorksheetFunction" ...